# Как записать id html объекта в переменную в javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно что бы при нажатии на html(`<div>`) объект, в переменную записывался его id!

```
function click(){
    var a = document.АЙДИ выбранного объекта;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (let i = 0; i < $divs.length; i++) {
    const element = $divs[i];
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let id = this.id;
        console.log(id);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это для первого `<div>` в [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')

div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.id)
})
```

```html
<div id="identifier">Here is ID</div>
```

Это для всех `<div>` на странице, c применением оператора [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
const divsCollection = document.querySelectorAll('div')

for (let div of divsCollection) {
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.id)
  })
}
```

```css
div { margin: .5rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
<div id="6">6</div>
```

Comment: Если один div окажется внутри другого - в итоге захватится самый старший. Может оказаться, что у всех элементов на странице id какой-нибудь `main-container` ) Здесь очень к месту «Делегирование Событий». P.s. `for(div of...` забыли `let`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо за полезный комментарий <3